# read in an xml server from Unity3D 4.xx

Tags: unity, server, xml

I need examples of how to read an xml from a server, using Unity3D..

I think it's something like this.. but I can not retrieve the information from the nodes..

An example would be of great help..
thank you..

var url = "http://server.com/test2.xml";

var www : WWW = new WWW (url);
  yield www;

var xml : XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using C#, you can use the XML classes from .NET. I tend to use the [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), since most of the time you need only to read out data, and don't have to write data back.

Snippet from my actual code:

```cs
XPathDocument xmlFile;

try {
  xmlFile = new XPathDocument (filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  UnityEngine.Debug.LogException (ex);
}

// Create the navigator to navigate the file
XPathNavigator xnav = xmlFile.CreateNavigator ();


// Get the values of single nodes directly by using their XPath
string viewmode = xnav.SelectSingleNode ("/trainingSettings/viewmode").Value;
int NoItems = xnav.SelectSingleNode ("/trainingSettings/difficulty/noitems").ValueAsInt;
int NoOverallItems = xnav.SelectSingleNode ("/trainingSettings/difficulty/nooverallitems").ValueAsInt;

// Convert values using XmlConvert …
TimeSpan RemainingDurationOfTraining = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan (xnav.SelectSingleNode ("/trainingSettings/trainingDuration").Value);
```

By using `XPathNavigator.Select()`, you can get a list of nodes back and then iterate over them, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll have to start programming in c # this part, the same code to use for Json?.

Comment: Also available, [System.XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8k674bf(v=vs.110).aspx)